# Launching Data Loader without a command (shell) window

Tags: data-loader

I just downloaded and installed the most recent version of data loader and I also had to install the Java Zulu OpenJDK 11 pack. I've successfully installed data loader and every time I run it, the command line opens and checks to see if the Java Zulu OpenJDK 11 pack has been installed, which it finds and then opens the normal data loader interface. My question is if this is now the normal data loader process when opening the app? Or, should the command window not open every time looking for the OpenJDK pack? Even after the normal data loader UI opens the command window remains open in the background until I close data loader. Previous versions of data loader that I've used didn't do this, so I'm just wondering if this is how it is now running when opening the app or if there is a configuration I need to make to stop the command window from opening every time I open data loader.

Comment: Out of the box  - yes, it's normal. You can fix it yourself - https://superuser.com/questions/140047/how-to-run-a-batch-file-without-launching-a-command-window

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing the default jarfile command in the registry.

1. In the registry go to this key: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jarfile\shell\open\command
2. Change the (Default) REG_SZ to "C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-11\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*" (Note: You may need to change the Zulu path in future updates.)
3. Create/Edit your desktop shortcut and change the Target to the dataloader path and reference the .jar file. Example: "C:\Users\YourName\dataloader\v51.0.1\dataloader-51.0.1-uber.jar"

That's it! You should now be able to launch dataloader without the command window from your shortcut.